# gsub! with Date.strptime not recognizing my date

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, gsub

I am trying to parse through a file and replace some days/dates.

For example, 
I want to change

```
In a post on the band's blog last night (06.05.12) 
to 
In a post on the band's blog sunday night
```

I am trying to use gsub! to do so.

```
r.gsub!(/\blast night \(([0-3][0-9]\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9])\)/ei,Date.strptime('\1',"%d.%m.%y").strftime("%A").to_s + ' night')
```

always says invalid date, but

```
r.gsub!(/\blast night \(([0-3][0-9]\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9])\)/ei,'\1')
```

shows the right date as 06.05.12
and

```
mydate = '06.05.12'
r.gsub!(/\blast night \(([0-3][0-9]\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9])\)/ei,Date.strptime(mydate,"%d.%m.%y").strftime("%A").to_s + ' night')
```

gives me the appropriate response. Why doesn't replacing mydate with \1 work when using Date.strptime?  Any suggestions on how to go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to try to reference the match group in your date function. This doesn't work though. The syntax is **only** available if you replace simple strings. The `gsub` function replaces all references in the passed string, but only when it is actually passed to the function. Your code is equivalent to

```
replacement = Date.strptime('\1',"%d.%m.%y").strftime("%A").to_s + ' night'
r.gsub!(/\blast night \(([0-3][0-9]\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9])\)/ei, replacement)
```

The "replacement" thus can't work as `'\1'` is not a valid date. The gsub replacement would only applied to the string returned by your `strftime` function. However, you can use the *magic* match variables which are set the the matching groups automatically:

```
r.gsub!(/\blast night \(([0-3][0-9]\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9])\)/ei) {
  Date.strptime($1,"%d.%m.%y").strftime("%A").to_s + ' night'
}
```

Notice that I wrote `$1` instead of `\1` in the `strptime` arguments

Comment: Thanks for describing why it wouldn't work.  That makes perfect sense.  I tried using $1, but I kept getting _can't dup NilClass_ with the $1 _magic_ match variable like so...  r.gsub!(/\blast night \(([0-3][0-9]\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9])\)/ei,Date.strptime($1,"%d.%m.%y").strftime("%A").to_s + 'night')

Comment: Hmmm, okay, the `$1` variable is only set in the block variant of `gsub`. I updated my answer. This should definitely work now. See [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) for details.

Comment: LOL, I just tried what your new suggestion was before seeing you had updated it.  I came back here to tell you what worked and saw you had exactly what I came up with.   Thank you so much!